# In Laravel Can I create a new Model Instance without new?

Tags: php, laravel

For example:
You can create a new model instance of User as:

```
new App\Model\User()
```

But when I use it in blade views, looks like:

```
new App\Model\User()->..->...
```

I think it is not a good way. It's not so elegant. 
So I want to add some methods to achieve that I can use like below in blade views:

```
User::instance()->..->...
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Thanks for helping. I know it is not a good way to call model in blade views. But in some cases, sometimes I still have chance calling model in blade views for convenient.
For example, in create blade form, usually use like this:

```
{!!Form::model(new App\Model\User, ['url' => '/', 'class' => 'form' ])!!}
```

So there is chance to use model in blade views. So I want to find a elegant way to get an instance of Model instead of using new App\Model\ModelName...
Like

```
User::instance()
```

to get a new instance of \App\Model\User.

Can scopeQuery in model works?

Comment: Maybe create some kind of custom helper function to make it look more clean?

Comment: why to use model in blade views ?? You should make helper function then call those methods in your views.

Comment: Never try to call models inside View.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in some cases, sometimes I call model in blade views for convenient.For example, in create blade form,usually use like this: {!!Form::model(new App\Model\User,['url' => '/', 'class' => 'form' ])!!}. So there is sometimes to use model in blade views.So I want to find a elegant way to get an instance of Model instead of new App\Model\ModelName...

Comment: @Germy Your controller should handle that. `return view('blade.file')->withModel(new App\Model\User);` then `{!! Form::model($model) !!}`.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thanks a lot, Maybe I should do like this. But I still wonder there is a good way to get a new instance of Model. Still thanks~

Comment: @JilsonThomas Thanks for suggestion~

Comment: @Drudge Thanks, I just wonder if there is a way to solve it~

Comment: @Dees040 That's a good idea, But I think if I can use like User::instance()  to create a new Model, It will be cooler and cleaner..

Comment: if you want to call model in your view then just do what @ceejayoz had said, but passing models in the view, i don't prefer. If you are using any framework then try to understand its philosophy first. Laravel is not build for doing task in your way .

Comment: @Drudge, Thanks~ I got it~

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you understand the concept of MVC you should know the relationship between a model, view and controller.

The controller as a middle man should do the work of passing appropriate data to your view.

This is a better way to do it in Laravel.

Your controller:

```
use App\Model\User;
class AccountController extends Controller{

       public function __construct (User $user){
              $this->user = $user;
       }


        public function profile(){
               return view('profile, ['user'=>$this->user]);
        }

 }
```

Then in your view, profile.blade.php

```
 Welcome {{$user->name}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot~ To be honest I know this usage. I know it is not a good way to call model in blade views. But in some cases, sometimes I still have chance calling model in blade views for convenient. For example, in create blade form, usually use like this:
{!!Form::model(new App\Model\User, ['url' => '/', 'class' => 'form' ])!!}
So there is chance to use model in blade views. So I want to find a elegant way to get an instance of Model instead of using new App\Model\ModelName... Like
User::instance() 
to get a new instance of \App\Model\User.